# Angular: What is the best approach to make five columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be the best approach to splitting the page into five columns like so in Angular?

Thank you and will be sure to accept the answer

Comment: This may help: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're using React doesn't matter, this is a CSS problem. There is probably a few ways to solve this, but you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>left</div>
  <div class='right'>right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.right {
    width: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.left {
    margin-right: 185px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGzbor

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, could you clarify on what `position: relative` and `position: absolute` are doing? Also how can I make the left column fluid, meaning make only the left column shrink in width as the browser size gets smaller?

Comment: First off, a div is a block-level element (read up on the display property to see the difference between a block, inline, inline-block element) which means it wants to take up the entire horizontal space available. We put a margin in to reserve space for our fixed-width column.

Comment: 2. Absolute positioning means that we can explicitly define the position of an element relative to a parent element that has it's positioning set to relative.  I know that probably doesn't make a lot of sense, but if you google it there are blogs that can explain it a lot a better than I can in a comment.

Comment: 3. We 'absolutely position' our fixed-wwidth column in the space that we reserved previously.

Answer (score 1):

Since you question is tagged [react-jsx](/questions/tagged/react-jsx), the best approach is to use ready-for-use layout components ,like : 
 [`react-bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) :

```
    import {Col} from 'react-boostrap';
    //...
    render() { 
      // ....
      <div className="raw" > 
         <Col md={6} mdPull={6} > 

         </Col>
         <Col md={6} mdPush={6} />

         </Col>
     </div>
    //
    }
```

[REF](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#grid)